# does react "render" children before passing them to parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to create a "Loader" HOC that would show a loader until loaded, and then render children. But I get an error in the JSX that I'm passing to the Loader that it `cant read .foo of null`.

It seems like the children get "rendered" (ie string interpolated etc) before getting passed to the Loader HOC; I was hoping that the children would be passed as a function or something and then evaluated only if the HOC's conditional requires the rendering of its children. Is this not the case?

```
const Loader = ({
  isLoading = false,
  children,
}) => {

  const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = React.useState(isLoading);

  // when isLoading changes, update showLoader
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(isLoading !== showLoader) {
      setShowLoader(isLoading);
    }
  }, [isLoading]);

  console.log(`Loader rendering with isLoading: ${isLoading} and showLoader: ${showLoader}`)
  return showLoader ? (<div> Loading... </div>) : children;
}

const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [recordData, setRecordData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // after 3 seconds, stop showing loader
    console.log('setting state...');
    setRecordData({ foo: 'bar '});
    setTimeout(() => setIsLoading(false), 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <Loader isLoading={isLoading}>
          <div>
            <p>This is the App, foo is {recordData.foo}</p>
          </div>
        </Loader>
    </div>
 );

}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: React builds a virtualDom tree that *roughly* "mirrors" the actual DOM tree. It then traverses the tree and calls "render" on each node to compute the renderable content. This is also the mechanism used during reconciliation to determine what may have changed and needs to be flushed to the real DOM.

Comment: I would think that even in a vDom "render" the values of the isLoading/showLoader variables would mean the "children" of Loader don't actually get rendered? Or does the vDom "render" of the App component include trying to render the Loader Components children regardless of Loaders component logic? (as opposed to the Children being passed to, and then "rendered" conditionally by Loader)

Comment: @DonaldP, "cant read .bar of null" but where you want it to read bar? I dont see such property in your code

Comment: @DmitryReutov my apologies that should have been '.foo of null', I've updated it. It's in the <Loader> components children where I read {recordData.foo}. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter when components render. The properties are calculated right in the moment where code finds them. `recordData.foo` is just an expression which is calculated by interpretator and pass calculated value as a child of `p`-element. So naturally at first rendering `recordData` is `null`, which causes error.

Comment: thank you, I assumed maybe it was the "calculated" value, appreciate the response